# Better position of two monitors in the labs

Tags: work-environment, ergonomics

Here in my lab, all my co-workers have dual monitors in their workstations.
They want to know the best position of the monitors, because some guys don't feel comfortable with both monitor aligned at horizontal and height in line to their heads.

I asked the medic but he said just to make a distance from a brace and set the height to head height.

**How can we determine the best position for dual screens that works for everyone?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ergonomics.

Comment: The consensus (at least of those who expressed an opinion) seems to be to allow ergonomics questions: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/is-ergonomics-on-topic

Comment: The alternative is to realise their is no 'best' position and to let people order them however they feel comfortable, they aren't robots who all think and feel the same thing after all

Comment: @RhysW i disagree - this is an ergonomics question, so there should be a "best" position.

Comment: @bharal i strongly disagree, if you find a position you are comfortable in that does not guarantee i find it comfortable atall

Comment: @RhysW that's true, of course. But ergonomics doesn't give a hoot that you like to slouch or that your core is as weak as a new born baby. Ergonomics is about the *optimum* position. Lots of people find terrible positions "comfortable" ~ but that doesn't mean they're not doing harmful long-term damage to their bodies. You *can* argue that people with physical abnormalities would require a different posture, but i doubt that's what you're gunning for.

Comment: Guys...this question isn't about ergonomics at all.  read the original question, before edits were made.  I feel that Michael Grubey tried to force context into the question where it didn't belong.  OP is asking how to find a proper compromise position for everyone in the office so that they all are comfortable.  This can't easily be answered at all.

Answer (score 8):

The best positioning is what works best for each individual. Allow (encourage, require) each person to set things up the best way that works **for them**. Attempting to force everyone into a single arrangement, or attempting to arrange things for a person without their direct input, will make everyone unhappy.

That your co-workers are asking someone else to set up their desk is a worry. What is preventing them from adjusting their own setup? Do they ask others to adjust their chairs for them as well?

For some people, finding the right positioning may mean giving up the second display altogether. I used to have a second display, but due to the arrangement of my desk, it was just not usable long-term. I ended up with terrible neck & shoulder pain and could never get things into an arrangement that was workable for me.

Answer (score 7):

There is no one-size-fits-all solution.  Many people use two monitors in landscape (default) orientation, and a common complaint is that mouse gestures (to cross from one edge to the other) are too big.  The relevance of that depends on how much you use the mouse, of course.

I use one portrait and one landscape, thus:

[image: photo]

(They're not really tilted; it's just a bad photo.)

The portrait one is mainly for things that want to be vertical -- documents, code, browser (for my usage patterns), etc.  The landscape one is for things that need the horizontal space -- spreadsheets with many columns, Outlook, some web pages, and so on.  As you can see in the screenshot, some things (like shells) work fine in either place.

You will also see from the photo that the monitors are not top-aligned.  Ideally you want to be looking straight at your monitor (and especially for LCD monitors where viewing angle subtly affects color), but with two large monitors, there's just too much -- you *can't* look straight at everything.  Through trial and error I identified what for me is optimal; looking straight ahead hits the top portion of the landscape monitor, and the "extra" for the portrait one is workable.  Meanwhile, nothing is too low to be usable, though the bottom part of the portrait monitor tends to be relegated to stuff where clear vision isn't as important.

(You'll see in this photo that my monitors are closer to the edge of the desk than most people's.  This is due to a vision issue; you will probably be more comfortable if you push them back as far as you can and still see clearly.)

Comment: I do the same (except the portrait one is on the right).  Works well for work where you need to see tall things (like source code) instead of wide things.

Answer (score 0):

**Normally**

One monitor directly in front of you, screen should be based on where the *middle* of your eyes would naturally fall when in your working position (presumably seated).

Other monitor to the side. You shouldn't be using the secondary monitor that much, most ~ 80% ~ of your work should have you in a neutral alignment facing the first monitor.

If you find your self looking at the secondary monitor for a while ( > 10 min )just drag whatever is on that screen to the primary monitor.

**Edge case**

If your work entails you always using both, then side-by side with neither directly in front of you is fine. This lets your head go from side to side naturally.

**General Idea**

Avoid prolonged  use with the head facing one direction or another - it is bad for you!

Comment: But how do you make this work for *everyone*?